# Como ocultar coluna do DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sqlite, datagridview

Possuo a função `void PopulaGrid(DataGridView grid, SQLiteDataReader dados)` que alimenta com dados o meu `dataGridViewAlunos`, eu gostaria de saber como faz para ocultar a *primeira* coluna do `dataGridViewAlunos` que é a coluna correspondente ao id do aluno (`id_aluno`), abaixo segue o código da função `PopulaGrid`:

```
void PopulaGrid(DataGridView grid, SQLiteDataReader dados) 
{
    grid.Rows.Clear();
    grid.Columns.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < dados.FieldCount; i++) 
    {
        DataGridViewColumn coluna = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        coluna.HeaderText = dados.GetName(i);
        coluna.Visible = true;
        coluna.Name = "coluna" + 1;
        coluna.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        grid.Columns.Add(coluna);
    }

    while (dados.Read()) 
    {
        object[] campos = new object[dados.FieldCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dados.FieldCount; i++)
            campos[i] = dados.GetValue(i);

        grid.Rows.Add(campos);
    }
}
```

Abaixo segue a minha função que retorna um `SQLiteDataReader` para alimentar o grid:

```
SQLiteDataReader FiltrarAlunos(string nome) 
{
    SQLiteDataReader dados = null;

    try
    {

        string query = "SELECT " +
                                "id_aluno AS 'Código', " +
                                "nome AS 'Nome', " +
                                "data_cadastro AS 'Data do Cadastro', " +
                                "telefone AS 'Telefone', " +
                                "celular AS 'Celular', " +
                                "endereco AS 'Endereço', " +
                                "observacao AS 'Observação', " +
                                "email AS 'E-Mail' " +
                                "FROM Alunos ";

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nome))
            query += "WHERE nome LIKE '%" + nome + "%'";

        DadosConexao dados_conexao = new DadosConexao();

        SQLiteConnection conexao = (new DALConexao(dados_conexao.String_Conexao).Conexao);
        conexao.Open();

        SQLiteCommand command = conexao.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = query;

        dados = command.ExecuteReader();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);               
    }

    return dados;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solução para ocultar a coluna desejada que é a `id_aluno` e utilizar a propriedade `Visible` da coluna, segue o código solucionado:

```
void PopulaGrid(DataGridView grid, SQLiteDataReader dados) 
{
    grid.Rows.Clear();
    grid.Columns.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < dados.FieldCount; i++) 
    {
        DataGridViewColumn coluna = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();

        coluna.HeaderText = dados.GetName(i);
        coluna.Visible = true;
        coluna.Name = "coluna" + 1;
        coluna.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        grid.Columns.Add(coluna);
    }

    while (dados.Read()) 
    {
        object[] campos = new object[dados.FieldCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < dados.FieldCount; i++)
            campos[i] = dados.GetValue(i);

        grid.Rows.Add(campos);
    }

    grid.Columns[0].Visible = false; //Mudei a propriedade Visible da coluna 0 que é a coluna id_aluno.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Se é garantido que é a primeira coluna, é bem fácil, basta começar pela segunda:

```
void PopulaGrid(DataGridView grid, SQLiteDataReader dados) {
    grid.Rows.Clear();
    grid.Columns.Clear();
    for (int i = 1; i < dados.FieldCount; i++) { // <========================== mudei aqui
        DataGridViewColumn coluna = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        coluna.HeaderText = dados.GetName(i);
        coluna.Visible = true;
        coluna.Name = "coluna" + 1;
        coluna.Resizable = DataGridViewTriState.True;
        grid.Columns.Add(coluna);
    }
    while (dados.Read()) {
        object[] campos = new object[dados.FieldCount];
        for (int i = 1; i < dados.FieldCount; i++) // <========================= mudei aqui
            campos[i] = dados.GetValue(i);
        grid.Rows.Add(campos);
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/HideColumnGridView.cs).

E tem que torar isto do SQL:

```
"id_aluno AS 'Código', " +
```

Não sei se tem outros pontos, mas já entendeu o que fazer para resolver tudo.

Este código é inseguro e tem problemas de arquitetura. Mas isto já estão fora do escopo da pergunta.

Comment: Ele ocultou a primeira coluna porem na segunda coluna que é a `nome` ficou o conteúdo do campo id (`id_aluno`) e o conteúdo da coluna nome foi para a terceira coluna.

Comment: Se quiser eu edito a pergunta e posto meu sql?

Comment: Esqueci de mudar embaixo.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, ocultou a coluna id, porem a coluna nome ficou com conteúdo vazio desta vez, e o conteúdo dela foi para as colunas adiantes, e com as outras colunas também, os seus respectivos conteúdos foram para a coluna diante.

Comment: Provavelmente tem que alterar em outros pontos do código também. Como só tem este trecho, só consigo ajudar até aí. Mas você já pegou onde está o problema, é só ver os outros locais onde precisa usar técnica semelhante. Tudo tem que ser deslocado em uma coluna.

Comment: Adicionei mais informações a pergunta.

Comment: Irei reformular a rotina da query, ja consegui resolver aqui.

Comment: Vou postar como resposta.